# How would I return the order of MongoDB Posts by time Favourited by user?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a web app with posts that the user can Favourite or "Like". When they fav a post the postId gets added to an array in the users collection.

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:this.userId},{$addToSet:{liked:postId}});
```

I am able to return these posts by retrieving this array of "liked" posts and using the `$in` operator.

```
Posts.find({ _id: { $in: user.liked } }, 
  {sort: {upcount: -1, views: -1} });
```

At the moment as you can see they are being sorted firstly by the `upcount` which is just the number of favs, and then by `views`.

What I want to eventually do though, is sort these results by the time that the user favourited the post. I'm sure I will have to record something like `timeFavourited` or something similar somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

*Note: Oddly MongoDB seems to record the quotes in the order they were favourited, but it doesn't retrieve them that way, if I leave out the sort option.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just recording what posts a user likes with:

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: this.userId },{ $addToSet: { liked: postId }});
```

Push an object that includes both the *postId* and current date

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: this.userId },
  { $push: { liked: { postId: postId, likedAt: new Date() }});
```

That solves your "where to store" question but it does complicate your life in other ways because your search/sort query is going to be more complicated. You'll also need to prevent dupes with code because while `$addToSet` does that for you automatically `$push` does not.

Comment: Thanks Michel, yes I imagined I'd have to record a new Date along with the time. This helps. I'm just going to have to get my head around how to actually implement this and as you said, how to handle dupes and call the search query. I'm sure this must have been done before though, so maybe someone else knows of an easy way...