# Return list of posts in order of time 'liked' as stored in User collection array

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

Okay, so here's my problem. I now have an array like this that is added to when a user 'likes' a post, which also captures the time that they have liked it.

```
"liked_times" : [                                                     
        {                                                          
                "postId" : "5CeN95hYZNK5uzR9o",                   
                "likedAt" : ISODate("2015-09-28T02:55:08.803Z") 
        },                                                         
        {                                                          
                "postId" : "vN7uZ2d6FSfzYJLmm",                   
                "likedAt" : ISODate("2015-09-28T02:55:26.118Z") 
        },                                                         
        {                                                          
                "postId" : "b5JEtHb9hCsQPeEQB",                   
                "likedAt" : ISODate("2015-09-28T02:55:31.359Z") 
        }                                                          
]
```

We used to just capture the postId, but updated to getting the time as well with this post [How would I return the order of MongoDB Posts by time Favourited by user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000889/how-would-i-return-the-order-of-mongodb-posts-by-time-favourited-by-user)

So then we used to be able to retrieve the posts with:

```
Posts.find({ _id: { $in: user.liked } }, 
  {sort: {createdAt: -1} });
```

But now I'm trying to work out how I would return the posts a user has liked in the order that he liked them using this new data. I'm sure there must be a relatively easy way.

**Edit as per comments**: I also have a simple array or list of docs with just the postId

```
"liked" : [
                "D4turxiezBvPtNjDr",
                "Hk2YpqgwRM4QCgsLv",
                "vN7uZ2d6FSfzYJLmm",
                "beNdpXhYLnKygD3yd",
                "EBMKgrD4DjZxkxvfY"
        ],
```

When a post is liked by the user the Id is added to the end of this list. However when I return posts with `return Quotes.find({ _id: { $in: user.liked } };` They are not ordered in the same order (I'm thinking due to a Minimongo local cache behaviour).

Is there another way I should be calling these docs to order them in the specific order that the array stores them? Or should I just go ahead and try to solve this using the `likedAt` times programatically in the code?

Comment: When you `$push` to an array the new item is appended to the end of the list, unless you modify the behavior. So the order should always be from oldest to most recent. Otherwise apply the [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier to push when storing. Otherwise the only way to re-order the array elements is etiher using `.aggregate()` or sorting the result in code. It's better to just store in the order you need, which seems to be the default order anyway.

Comment: Yes @BlakesSeven I observed that it was storing them in the order that they were being liked, but I found that for some reason they weren't being returned in that order. I'm thinking it may be something to do with Meteor's handling of published posts etc and some posts already being in the local MiniMongo cache or something. I'll have to have another look, or perhaps handle this programatically in the code. Thanks.

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible example that shows items returned in a different order to storage then by all means please do so. Arrays are index ordered always, and pushing items appends to the array, unless modified with `$sort` as mentioned. So if you have different behavior then please show the code that produces this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MongoDB's $in clause guarantee order? If not, how to get them in order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order-if-not-how-to-get-them-in-order)